# Writing a query to get a value depending on values of 2 rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a database table named `order_data` that contains data like this:

| id | order_id | data_value | data_key |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9825 | 1156 | 2023-05-15 | date |
| 9826 | 1156 | 123 | product_id |

Each order (`order_id`) generates these rows, so there can be multiple rows in this table which have the same `order_id`.

How do I write a MySQL query to get the `order_id` when:

- `data_key` = `date` AND `data_value` = `2023-05-15`
- `data_key` = `product_id` AND `data_value` = `123`

I know how to do this for each individual one above, but not sure if trying to account for both of the above together, can it be done in a single query?

I have tried:

```
SELECT order_id FROM `order_data` WHERE `data_key` = 'product_id' AND `data_value` = '123' AND `data_key` = 'date' AND `data_value` = '2023-05-15';
```

But this does not return the `order_id`, returns no results.

Comment:  Please never post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551) of data, code or errors.

Comment: Apologies - updated and noted

Comment: @ErgestBasha I have added the query attempted to the question.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using EXISTS

Consider the following data example

```
create table order_data (
  id int ,
  order_id int ,
  data_value varchar(15) ,
  data_key varchar(15)
) ;


insert into order_data values 
(9825,1156,'2023-05-15','date'),
(9826,1156,'123','product_id');
```

Query

```
select * from order_data
where order_id=1156
AND data_value='2023-05-15' AND data_key='date' 
AND EXISTS (select 1 from order_data where data_value='123' AND data_key='product_id') ;
```

An index on (order_id,data_value,data_key) will speed up the query

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/9YAVPwAD)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using `inner join` as follows :

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.order_id
FROM order_data t
inner join (
  SELECT order_id 
  FROM order_data 
  WHERE data_key = 'date' AND data_value = '2023-05-15'
) as s on s.order_id = t.order_id
WHERE t.data_key = 'product_id' AND t.data_value = '123';
```

`DISTINCT` will prevent getting duplicates `order_id` if somehow one of the rows is duplicated

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/027Za4TB)

Comment: That's True, It can be removed if the OP is sure there is no duplicates